# Disable select option list if another select option list is selected

Tags: javascript, select

I have to make select list option in form, where, if visitor will select one of options from select list 'first stage A' or 'second stage A' then 'first stage B' and 'second stage B' is disabled to select And inversely, if visitor will select 'first stage B' or 'second stage B' then 'first stage A' and 'second stage A' is disabled.

heres piece of sample code where I want to disable some parts if selected

```
first stage A <select name="first-stage-A">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="first-stage-1-A-1">first-stage-A-1</option>
                <option value="first-stage-1-A-2">first-stage-A-2</option>
                <option value="first-stage-1-A-3">first-stage-A-3</option>
                <option value="first-stage-1-A-4">first-stage-A-4</option>
              </select><br />

first stage B <select name="first-stage-B">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="first-stage-1-B-1">first-stage-B-1</option>
                <option value="first-stage-1-B-2">first-stage-B-2</option>
                <option value="first-stage-1-B-3">first-stage-B-3</option>
                <option value="first-stage-1-B-4">first-stage-B-4</option>
              </select><br />

second stage A <select name="second-stage-A">
                 <option value=""></option>
                 <option value="second-stage-A-1">second-stage-A-1</option>
                 <option value="second-stage-A-2">second-stage-A-2</option>
                 <option value="second-stage-A-3">second-stage-A-3</option>
                 <option value="second-stage-A-4">second-stage-A-4</option>
               </select><br />

second stage B <select name="second-stage-B">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="second-stage-B-1">second-stage-B-1</option>
                  <option value="second-stage-B-1">second-stage-B-2</option>
                  <option value="second-stage-B-1">second-stage-B-3</option>
                  <option value="second-stage-B-1">second-stage-B-4</option>
               </select>
```

and [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4c9u2855/)

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yup, jquery available

Comment: This seems like a weird user experience. You probably want to force the user to do the first stage then the second stage and build the second stage's options based on what was selected in the first stage. The structure would be better for the user and easier to code.

Comment: @catalyst294 yup, but also I would like to show all available options for user to reconsider whith one he would select

Comment: @chev That is what I'm getting at. You should have only two select controls, one for the first stage (containing the A and B options) then from that one's selected value build the second stage's options from those that are possible based on the first stage's selection. See something like this where the Make's value determines the Model's options (http://www.autotrader.com/) I think this is probably similar to your workflow.